# How to use DataContractJsonSerializer with Generics

Tags: generics, asp.net-core, f#, deserialization, json-deserialization

I found this example at [Convert an object to json, and json to object](http://www.fssnip.net/1l/title/Convert-an-object-to-json-and-json-to-object)  to deserializing string to JSON while passing the type and vice versa.

```
/// Object to Json 
let internal json<'t> (myObj:'t) =   
        use ms = new MemoryStream() 
        (new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<'t>)).WriteObject(ms, myObj) 
        Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray()) 


/// Object from Json 
let internal unjson<'t> (jsonString:string)  : 't =  
        use ms = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(jsonString)) 
        let obj = (new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<'t>)).ReadObject(ms) 
        obj :?> 't
```

**Context**:

For a type Document

```
[<DataContract>]
type Document = {
    [<field: DataMemberAttribute(Name="name")>]
    Name: string

    [<field: DataMemberAttribute(Name="version")>]
    Version: string
}
```

**JSON**

```
let str = """{"name: "test"; version="97234982734"}"""
```

**Question**

How to call `json` and `unjson` functions using my example?

Why are the functions specified as internal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this sort of operation, I typically use: `System.Web.Extensions.JavaScriptSerializer` class. It's got easy to use `Serialize` and `Deserialize` methods which work well with Generics.

You'll need to include a reference to the `System.Web.Extensions` assemblies.

Msdn link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

No, WCF attributes ( i.e. `DataContract` or `DataMember`) are required.

The way I understand it the serializer classes youre trying to use are used in the WCF internal for serialization.

Code sample:

```
/// Object to Json 
let internal json<'t> (myObj:'t) =   
     let ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()   
     ser.Serialize(myObj)

/// Object from Json 
let internal unjson<'t> (jsonString:string)  : 't =  
    let ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer() 
    let obj = ser.Deserialize<'t>(jsonString)
    obj
```

**EDIT**

If you are using .NET Core, you will not have access to this assembly.  Please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45687851/how-to-add-system-web-extensions-assembly-to-net-core-project-in-vscode), for an alternative approach using `Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: nice, but I didn't get to see F# example there, any implementation for my example code?

Comment: I'll see how close I can get on my phone without IDE or syntax check... Here goes...

Comment: thanks for the code, I'll accept the answer but you know what, I'm on .net core, I don't have this library :-)

Comment: @App2015 please see update related to .NET Core.  Hope this helps!