# 'Extensions' and 'Script' does not exist in namespace 'System.Web'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

Hi im using razor pages asp.net c# and Im trying to use `System.Web.Extensions` and using `System.Web.Script`; and
using `System.Web.Script.Serialization`;
Because if i remove these references i get other errors:

> 'error CS0103: The name 'CommandType' does not exist in the current
> context'
>
> 'error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'JavaScriptSerializer' could
> not be found'

I tried looking on internet for solutions but ive had no success. Here is my code, hopefully you guys can help me

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Extensions;
using System.Web.Script;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using myWebApp.Database;
using myWebApp.Models;
using myWebApp.Pages;
using myWebApp.Hubs;
using Npgsql;

namespace myWebApp.Controllers
{
    public class SpeedListener :Controller
    {
        private IHubContext<speedalarmhub> _hubContext;
        private IMemoryCache _cache;
        public SpeedListener(IHubContext<speedalarmhub> hubContext,IMemoryCache cache)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
            _cache = cache; 
        }
        public string cs = Database.Database.Connector();
        public void ListenForAlarmNotifications()
        {
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
            conn.StateChange += conn_StateChange;
            conn.Open();
            var listenCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
            listenCommand.CommandText = $"listen notifyalarmspeed;";
            listenCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Notification += PostgresNotificationReceived;
            _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync(this.GetAlarmList());
            while (true)
            {
                conn.Wait();
            }
        }
        private void PostgresNotificationReceived(object sender, NpgsqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {

            string actionName = e.Payload.ToString();
            string actionType = "";
            if (actionName.Contains("INSERT"))
            {
                actionType = "Insert";
            }
            _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", this.GetAlarmList());
        }
        public string GetAlarmList()
        {
            var AlarmList = new List<string>();
            using (NpgsqlCommand sqlCmd = new NpgsqlCommand())
            {
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "sp_alarm_speed_process_get";
                NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
                conn.Open();
                sqlCmd.Connection = conn;
                using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        NotificationModel model = new NotificationModel();
                        
                    // you must fill  your model items
                        AlarmList.Add(model.Bericht);
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                    conn.Close();
                }



            }
            _cache.Set("SpeedAlarm", SerializeObjectToJson(AlarmList));
            return _cache.Get("SpeedAlarm").ToString();
        }
        public String SerializeObjectToJson(Object alarmspeed)
        {
            try
            {
                var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                return  jss.Serialize(alarmspeed);
            }
            catch (Exception) { return null; }
        }
        private void conn_StateChange(object sender, System.Data.StateChangeEventArgs e)
        {

            _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Current State: " + e.CurrentState.ToString() + " Original State: " + e.OriginalState.ToString(), "connection state changed");
        }
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Yes, `JavaScriptSerializer` is part of `System.Web.Extensions`. So what's the question?
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Extensions/Script/Serialization/JavaScriptSerializer.cs,d0a9bc29c74591f9

Comment: You can use `Newtonsoft.Json` for serialization, if you don't want to include the libraries you mentioned. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45687971/395500

Comment: I think you need add reference to some dlls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520569/where-can-i-find-the-assembly-system-web-extensions-dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'error CS0103: The name 'CommandType' does not exist in the current context'

To fix this error, you can try to add:

```
using System.Data;
```

> 'error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'JavaScriptSerializer' could not be found'

For JSON serialization in ASP.NET Core applications, as @Marshal mentioned in comment, `Newtonsoft.Json` could be used.

And since .NET Core 3, [the default JSON serializer for ASP.NET Core is now `System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-3.0?view=aspnetcore-5.0#new-json-serialization) that would be higher performance than `Newtonsoft.Json`.

```
return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(alarmspeed);
```

Note: `System.Text.Json` may not provide complete parity with Newtonsoft.Json features that list in following doc, you can check it for detailed information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#table-of-differences-between-newtonsoftjson-and-systemtextjson